# Problem in using "VisualRecognitionV3" of IBM-Watson

Tags: python, ibm-watson

I have been using "VisualRecognitionV3" for demographic detection for 6 months. But all of sudden now am getting this error "WatsonApiException: Error: Not a valid request, Code: 404 , X-dp-watson-tran-id: gateway01-2177487933 , X-global-transaction-id: 7ecac92c5d8d72bb81c9d43d". Please help me in dubugging this.

Code that is generating this error is:

```
visual_recognition.detect_faces(url='https://mediaslide-europe.storage.googleapis.com/immmodels/pictures/1293/2856/large-1550679129-03a161d94f3054b739fa5a8a310e7cb5.jpg').get_result()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That will be because as of 12 September 2019, the Detect Faces methods were removed from the Visual Recognition service.

Check the release notes : 
https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/visual-recognition?topic=visual-recognition-release-notes